# What is Phablet?

Tags: tablet, hardware

How to define a **phablet**?

I first read this word in article about "[ZTE building some Galaxy Note-style phablets](http://crave.cnet.co.uk/mobiles/zte-building-two-galaxy-note-style-phablets-50007736/)". This is something larger than a smartphone, but smaller than a tablet. But where is the boundary? What features would a device have (apart from size) to be considered smartphone/phablet/tablet ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phablets are basically tablet / phone crossovers. Best examples are Samsung’s Galaxy Note and LG’s Optimus Vu.

As per [ComputerWorld](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9224363/Rise_of_the_phablet_): 
*A **phablet** is a phone with a screen so big that it can be used as a tablet.*

There are no defined boundaries whatsoever in terms of screen sizes; so any tablet with phone (telephony) capabilities might also be termed *a phablet*.

Comment: Although I don't doubt upon this, I'd love to here what other people have to say about the "phablet" concept. :)